# Critical error: wait for JVM process failed

Tags: windows, java-ee, java

Всем привет.

Установил на Windows 7 - Tomcat и JBoss. Не получается установить JBoss как сервис, использоваю Wrapper. После запуска команды:

```
wrapper.exe -c %JBOSS_HOME%\server\YOURCONFIG\wrapper\wrapper.conf
```

выдает ошибку:

> `wrapper  | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed`

Как это можно устранить ?

**Добавлено.**

Вот что в логах пишет:

> `WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class <YourMainClass>: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <YourMainClass>`
>
> `WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
> java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]`
>
> `Where:
> app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
> app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the application.`

сылка на wrapper.conf
[wrapper.conf](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1DD9dg_vLhunqrWcp-mZCsuELlBG1L2FkENN_rMr_M9Q)

Comment: Мало информации. Ошибка могла произойти из-за чего угодно.

Смотрите лог wrapper.log, предварительно включив режим отладки wrapper.debug=true в файле wrapper.conf

Comment: Вывод логов добавлен в вопрос.

Comment: скиньте куда-нибудь wrapper.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо ребята за помошь

после обновлений с JBoss-5.0.0 на JBoss-6.0.0 проблема решилась

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать путь к классам JBoss:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JBOSS_HOME%/lib/*.jar
```